# Ruby nested iteration to match strings within an array

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to figure out from an array of strings how to compare strings based on characters. So for example there's the following:

```
arr = [4, "string", "gnirts", "strign", "ta", "atc"]
```

In this case "ta" and "atc" do not match the other strings. But "string", "gnirts", "strign" match.

My first thought would be to break the array apart, do a length check. Then compare the strings and keep the first present.

I know I don't care about the 4. It's just indicating the number of strings so I can do an arr.shift(1).

I know I could do something like string.chars.sort but how do I compare the strings within the arrays?

I was thinking something like:

```
arr.each_with_index do |value, index|
 index.each do |item|
  if value.chars.sort == item
   return value
 end
end
```

That definitely does not work.

What I'm wanting to end up seeing would then have a sort on the array so I'd end up with atc, gnirts, and string (because the others match against it and string comes first).

So how do I ultimately compare strings within an array and keep the first one numerically?

EDIT:
Input would be something like [4, "string", "gnirts", "strign", "ta", "atc"]
Output array would be

```
["atc", "ta", "string"]
```

So matching would keep the first present and then sort on those not matched.

Comment: Given `arr`, can you post clearly the expected output ?array

Comment: Edited post with expected output. There would be a removal on matching strings based on the first present then sorted alphabetically

Comment: You have not explained what "match" means in '"ta" and "atc" do not match the other strings'. If fact, I wasn't able to figure that out until I read max's answer. You need to state that two strings match if one is an anagram of the other.

Comment: You really have three questions rolled into one: "How do I skip the `4` at the beginning ?"; "Of each group of strings that are anagrams of each other, how do I select only the first of the group?"; and "After answering the first two questions how do I sort the resulting array by length?". It's generally best to limit multi-part questions to the central one, particularly when the answers to the others (here the first and last) are pretty obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
input = [4, "string", "gnirts", "strign", "ta", "atc"]

input.
  drop(1).
  group_by { |str| str.chars.sort.join }.
  values.
  map(&:first)

# => ["string", "ta", "atc"]
```

Going through line by line:

```
input.

  drop(1).
  # => ["string", "gnirts", "strign", "ta", "atc"]]

  group_by { |str| str.chars.sort.join }.
  # => {
  #      "ginrst" => ["string", "gnirts", "strign"],
  #      "at"     => ["ta"],
  #      "act"    => ["atc"]
  #    }

  values.
  # => [
  #       ["string", "gnirts", "strign"],
  #       ["ta"],
  #       ["atc"]
  #    ]

  map(&:first)
  # => ["string", "ta", "atc"]
```

As lacostenycoder mentioned you may want to reverse the output to match what's expected.

It is possibly to do this using other Enumerable methods such as `reduce`, `each`, etc. however [`group_by`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/group_by) is more idiomatic and I would recommend reading up on Ruby's Enumerable class because you can get a lot done with method chaining, if you know all the methods that are available to you.

Comment: perhaps add `.reverse` based on OPs example

Comment: `str.chars.sort.join` smart!

Comment: @iGian I am kinda surprised there isn't a `String#sort` method to be honest

Comment: You may want to use `input.drop(1)`, `input[1..-1]` or `input[1..]` instead of the destructive `shift` operation.

Comment: Consider using `uniq` rather than `group_by`. You don't need `join`. `str.each_char.sort` avoids the creation of the temporary array `str.chars`. The OP implied there is only one non-string in the array, and it is at the beginning, but it may be desirable to generalise to permit any number of non-strings (including zero) at any locations.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I agree with all your points except for the advice to use uniq instead of group_by

Comment: @CarySwoveland I just find `group_by` flows very well, I don't see the benefit of using uniq

Answer (score 3):

```
require 'set'

arr.grep(String).uniq { |obj| obj.each_char.to_set }.sort_by(&:size)
  #=> ["ta", "atc", "string"]
```

The doc for [Array#uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-uniq) states, "`self` is traversed in order, and the first occurrence is kept.", meaning that, among `"string"`, `"gnirts"` and `"strign"`, `"string"` has the smallest index in the array (`1`), so it is the one that is retained by `uniq`.

One could replace `obj.each_char.to_set` with `obj.each_char.sort` but the latter is less efficient if the array is large.

Replace `grep(String)` with `drop(1)` if it is known that there is exactly one non-string and it is the first element of the array.

Comment: Also: `arr.grep(String)` is a handy way of sifting out only String type objects. For type checking usually best to do `obj.is_a?(String)` rather than literal class comparison `obj.class == String`. Worth noting that `String === obj` is the equalsy way of doing it, and only in that order as `Class#===` is a special case.

Comment: @tadman, thanks. I edited. I like `String === obj` but am concerned that it may not be understood by some readers, and there's always the possibility of inadvertently tapping that key twice rather than thrice.

Comment: Typo here: `obj.class.is_a? String` should just be `obj.is_a? String`.